# Android Widgets: Not able to retain old values

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent

I will make it simple. I have my widget code. My  widget layout contains a linear layout with one button in it. In my widget code, I initialize a String List with some values in it.
When I click the button in my widget, I have to update my List with some more values.

So, this is my code,

```
List<String> myList = null;
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
myList = new List<String>();
myList.add("1");
myList.add("2");
...
Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
intent.setAction("CALL_UPDATE");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
....
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("CALL_UPDATE")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Intent received"+myList , 2000).show();
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, the broadcast is properly received by onReceive(). The problem is, on onReceive(), I see my list as null instead of some values in it as some string objects were added earlier.

Can anyone help?

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation says:

> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: ***anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available***, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.
>
> ***In particular, you may not show a dialog*** or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the
>   NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use
>   Context.startService() to send a command to the service.

And:

> onReceive() is normally called within the main thread of its process,
>   so you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a
>   timeout of **10 seconds** that the system allows before considering the
>   receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed). You cannot
>   launch a popup dialog in your implementation of onReceive().

**Edit**:
AppWidgetProvider is a `BroadcastReceiver` and it's instance (and so it's fields) will be deleted after it's lifcycle.When you create a new instance of widget in HomeScreen,`onUpdate` and `onReceive` of AppWidgetProvider invoke and list of this instance of AppWidgetProvider is not null.But after invoking onReceive (for example 10 seconds)this instance will delete.When you click on button ,second instance of AppWidgetProvider will be create and it's list is null.
You can save your list `public static field` of a class and retrieve it when you need.

Comment: Thx for the good info... It makes sense. I may have to look for some other way to get around the problem.

Comment: @rahul I note asimple way in end of my answer.See it.

Comment: hasanghaforian: Naming the members static works. Thx for the info and the solution.